# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'. On Simple SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting an error on a query which worked for another similar task but in this case does not. All I want to do is copy the values from a column in one table to another:

```
UPDATE   dbo.JobClients 
SET JobClients.[Status] = dbo.Jobs.[Status]
INNER JOIN dbo.JobClients 
ON dbo.Jobs.Id = dbo.JobClients.JobId
```

I added the square brackets around the "Status" because it was highlighting blue and I thought it may be a reserved word, but even so the error isn't pointing to that being the problem:

> *Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.*

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `FROM` clause. Try this instead:

```
UPDATE  c
SET c.[Status] = j.[Status]
FROM dbo.JobClients  AS c
INNER JOIN dbo.JobClients AS j ON j.Id = c.JobId
```

Comment: Thanks, that's got me further. However I'm now getting the error: 
"The multi-part identifier "dbo.Jobs.Id" could not be bound."

Comment: @EllyReed See my edit, if you used aliases use them instead of `dbo.Jobs.Id` use `j.Id`. But does that table `Jobs` has a column `Id`??

Comment: Yes, that worked like a charm, just needed to change the "dbo.JobClients AS j" to "dbo.Jobs AS j" THANKYOU!!